# Training a model to be biased to a given background

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am re-training an inception resnet v2 model to recognize a sequence of 3 digit numbers(of a particular font type).The sequence is artificially generated with black lettering on a white background. I am of the opinion that subjecting the model to see only a specific background will help me eliminate false detections(in this case any other 3 digit sequence not on a white background), as the model will not predict(high probabilities) for sequences whose backgrounds are not white.Is it a valid assumption to make?

PS:I have tried using tesseract previously to perform text extraction from an image. I used east text detector for detection, which gave me the bounding boxes for the text. I followed that with OCR using pytesseract, but it always returned an empty string. Furthermore, on rotating of the digits, east-text detector failed to recognize the rotated sequence of digits. I was hence left with no option but to train and perform text detection and extractiion using a Neural Network Model.

code for pytesseract:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import  image_to_string
from PIL import Image
refPt=[(486,302),(540,308),(538,328),(484,323)] #the bbox returned by east
refpt = np.array(refPt,dtype=np.int32)
roi_corners=np.array(refPt[0:4],np.int32).reshape((-1,1,2))
inp_img=cv2.imread("1.jpg")
mask = np.zeros(inp_img.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
channel_count = inp_img.shape[2]
ignore_mask_color = (255,)*channel_count
mask = cv2.fillPoly(mask,   np.array(refPt[0:4],np.int32).reshape((-1,1,2))], ignore_mask_color)
masked_image = cv2.bitwise_and(inp_img, mask)
print (image_to_string(Image.fromarray(masked_image),lang='eng'))
```

[image: This is a sample image on which OCR was performed following the text detection]
[image: This is a rotated image on which east text detector fails to recognize the sequence of digits]

Comment: Are you just looking for a way to extract digits from your image? Or is it absolutely necessary for you to train a model for this task?

Comment: Well,I am not looking for an image processing solution for extraction of digits,but rather a ML solution for combining the detection and extraction into a single step.

Comment: Okay. Any particular reason why you are not using [tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/) directly?

Comment: it doesnot detect. I get an empty string as my output.

Comment: Is it possible for you to show some sample code that you have tried, using tesseract? Since your text is black and your background is white, tesseract must be able to detect it. Please post some sample image(s) as well so that we can understand what kind of images you are dealing with.